# How to Iterate through a range of dates?

Tags: java, date

I am trying to iterate through strings of dates. The strings are in the format  like this 2000.07.28. I tried converting them to doubles but then it complains. I also need to keep the same format for the dates. Because I need to print certain dates. 
I tried this:

```
  String begDate = "1999.11.18";
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new     SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
  Date start = sdf.parse("2010.01.01");
  Date end = sdf.parse("2010.04.01");
  GregorianCalendar gcal = new GregorianCalendar();
  gcal.setTime(start);
  while (!gcal.getTime().after(end))
 {
      Date d = gcal.getTime();
      System.out.println(d);
      gcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
  }
```

But while it does iterate through the dates correctly it changes the date format.

Comment: @Ninjascroll86 That first line of code seems superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

## `Date`/`Calendar` have no format

You seem to be confusing the `Date`/`Calendar` object with the textual representation of its value generated as a String by the `toString` method. Neither `Date` nor `Calendar` have a format. Each has a `toString` method you are calling implicitly in your line `System.out.println( d );`. The format used by `toString` when generating a String is its own default format pattern, not the format pattern you specified while parsing.

This line:

```
System.out.println( d );
```

…is a shortcut for this next line, with the implicit call to [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) made explicit:

```
System.out.println( d.toString() );
```

That `toString` method uses its own format (a clumsy, poorly designed format) of the form `dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy`.

## java.time

You are using old legacy classes that have proven to be poorly design, confusing, and troublesome. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later (and [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).

For a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

To specify a formatting pattern for parsing, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

This example code spits out `LocalDate` values represented textually in your desired format. At the same time this code collects each `LocalDate` in the sequence in a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy.MM.dd" );
LocalDate start = sdf.parse("2010.01.01");
LocalDate end = sdf.parse("2010.04.01");
LocalDate localDate = start;
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
while ( ! localDate.isAfter( end ) ) {
    i = i + 1;
    dates.add( localDate );
    String output = localDate.format( formatter );
    System.out.println( "LocalDate # " + i + " : " + output );
    // Set up next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusDays( 1 );
}
System.out.println( "dates : " + dates.toString() );
```

When printing the `List` of `LocalDate` objects, notice each `LocalDate` object’s [`LocalDate::toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) method generates a String using sensible formats from the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Tips:

- Do most of your work in objects like `LocalDate` rather than Strings. For business logic, use smart objects. When you need to present user, then generate Strings in a certain format.
- When exchanging data or serializing values, if at all possible, use standard ISO 8601 formats rather than inventing your own such as `yyyy.MM.dd`.